# X-Editable putting "Empty" after successful update

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am using X-Editable plugin for inline editing on a table but I am getting a annoying problem. After the successful request and the successful updates, the plugin puts "Empty" instead the correct updated value on the table cell.

My site is restful, so I am doing PUT requests to URLs like `http://example.com/admin/year/<id>` to make database updates.

I've made a JSFiddle to show my problem, but on JSFiddle, the X-Editable keeps the infinite "loading" after ajax request. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/wqqr3cL3/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! Got it! To solve this problem I used the attribute `display` of X-Editable. So, from X-Editable `display` attribute [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html):

> Callback to perform custom displaying of value in element's text. If
>   `null`, default input's display used. If `false`, no displaying methods
>   will be called, element's text will never change. Runs under element's
>   scope.

I updated my code and after the response from AJAX request, I update the text this way:

```
//ommited x-editable other code...        
display: function (value, sourceData, response) {
   $(this).html(response.value);
}
```

Here an working example but using text box. I used a select box. The link: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/278/

Comment: I have the same problem but was unable to understand your answer - any help? I asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717683/xeditable-select2-dropdown-w-ajax-source-displaying-empty-after-submitting

Comment: 8+ Years later and this answer still works.  The jsfiddle didn't work for me, but adding the display function was successful.  Thank you!