# xeditable & select2 dropdown w/ajax source displaying empty after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, x-editable

I've gotten `xeditable` and `select2` to work with an `api` call as the source and everything works great EXCEPT the following.

After submitting the select2 dropdown, the value of the table is displayed as `EMPTY` and requires a page refresh in order to update to the correct value.

Does anyone know how to update the value to the selected `select2` dropdown value?

my html:

```
<td class="eo_role"><a href="#" data-pk={{r.pk}} data-type="select2" data-url="/api/entry/{{r.pk}}/"
data-name="eo_role" data-title="Enter EO_role">{{r.eo_role}}</a></td>
```

here is my JS:

```
$('#example .eo_role a').editable( {
    params: function(params) {  //params already contain `name`, `value` and `pk`
      var data = {};
      data[params.name] = params.value;
      return data;
    },
    source: 'http://localhost:8000/api/eo_role/select_two_data/',
    tpl: '<select></select>',
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'put'
        },
    select2: {
        cacheDatasource:true,
        width: '150px',
        id: function(pk) {
            return pk.id;
        },
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/eo_role/select_two_data/',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            processResults: function(item) {return item;}    
        }
    },
    formatSelection: function (item) {
        return item.text;
    },
    formatResult: function (item) {
        return item.text;
    },
    templateResult: function (item) {
        return item.text;
    },
    templateSelection : function (item) {
        return item.text;
    }, 
});
```

Again - everything works (database updates, dropdownlist populates etc.) however the `<td>` gets updated with `"EMPTY"` after submitting the dropdown - requiring a page refresh to show the correct value.

Comment: I tried similar problem/solution of the linked but didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190106/x-editable-putting-empty-after-successful-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I'm SUPER PUMPED.

```
//outside of everything, EVERYTHING
//test object is a global holding object that is used to hold the selection dropdown lists
//in order to return the correct text.
var test = {};

$('#example .eo_role a').editable( {
    params: function(params) {  //params already contain `name`, `value` and `pk`
      var data = {};
      data[params.name] = params.value;
      return data;
    },

    //MUST be there - it won't work otherwise.
    tpl: '<select></select>',
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'put'
        },
    select2: {

        width: '150px',
        //tricking the code to think its in tags mode (it isn't)
        tags:true,
        //this is the actual function that triggers to send back the correct text.
        formatSelection: function (item) {
            //test is a global holding variable set during the ajax call of my results json.
            //the item passed here is the ID of selected item. However you have to minus one due zero index array.
            return test.results[parseInt(item)-1].text;
        },
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/eo_role/select_two_data/',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            processResults: function(item) {
            //Test is a global holding variable for reference later when formatting the selection.
            //it gets modified everytime the dropdown is modified. aka super convenient.
            test = item;
            return item;}    
        }
    },  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced that same issue. I handle it that way:

In x-editable source code look for:

```
   value2html: function(value, element) {
     var text = '', data,
     that = this;
     if(this.options.select2.tags) { //in tags mode just assign value
       data = value;
       //data = $.fn.editableutils.itemsByValue(value, this.options.select2.tags, this.idFunc);
       } else if(this.sourceData) {
          data = $.fn.editableutils.itemsByValue(value, this.sourceData, this.idFunc);
       } else {
          //can not get list of possible values
          //(e.g. autotext for select2 with ajax source)
       }
```

As you can see, there is else statment, without any code (only 2 comments) that is the situation, with which we have a problem. My solution is to add missing code:

```
(...) else {
      //can not get list of possible values
      //(e.g. autotext for select2 with ajax source)
      data = value;
}
```

That's fix problem without tags mode enabled. I do not detect any unwanted behaviors so far.
Example code:

```
jQuery('[data-edit-client]').editable({
    type: 'select2',
    mode: 'inline',
    showbuttons: false,
    tpl: '<select></select>',
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'POST'
    },
    select2: {
        width: 200,
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: 'Wybierz klienta',
        allowClear: false,
        formatSelection: function (item) {
            //test is a global holding variable set during the ajax call of my results json.
            //the item passed here is the ID of selected item. However you have to minus one due zero index array.
            return window.cacheData[parseInt(item)].text;
        },
        ajax: {
            url: system.url + 'ajax/getProjectInfo/',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                projectID: system.project_id,
                action: 'getProjectClients',
                customer: parseInt(jQuery("[data-edit-client]").attr("data-selected-company-id"))
            },
            processResults: function (response) {
                window.cacheData = response.data.clients;
                return {
                    results: response.data.clients
                };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That didn't work for me - it's posting the data correctly to the server, just still showing "Empty" string after selection.

Comment: Well... xEditable is poorly maintained. I think, best solution is to use directly [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: I'd agree - except I know very little about javascript in general, and having the inline editable function is extremely valuable. If only there was another option.